# 3 days still unconfirmed transaction!

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I have never had this happen before it's been three days and still unconfirmed has anybody else experienced this!?! Will it ever confirm?

https://blockchain.info/tx/5d054c0f9a686a67f3be86b3fb8b91f5f61291145714dcf466f64ebc45b71019?show_adv=true

Comment: Received Time 2017-02-22 15:08:22 How is it 3 days?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bitcoin core, you can try to erase the transactions in your wallet.dat file with pywallet. (https://github.com/jackjack-jj/pywallet)

Then you only have the keys left in your wallet.dat. When you start Bitcoin, you'll need to start it with CLI and add the option -rescan.

Your BTC should appear in your balance as unspent. You can then send them again, with a higher fee. When that transaction will confirm, the old one will automatically be rejected because it'll be a double spend.

But in the end, it makes you able to send your BTC again. :)

**REMEMBER : ALWAYS BACKUP YOUR WALLET.DAT FILE BEFORE DOING ANYTHING !**